# assigning numbers to letters

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I'm trying to solve a problem of cryptography (assigning numbers to letters)

GERALD + DONALD = ROBERT

Each letter represents a different number (between 0 and 9). 
The first letter of each word represents a digit different from 0.

The problem :

the software does not display errors and does not display a solution.

```
    %values between 0 and 9
valeur(0).
valeur(1).
valeur(2).
valeur(3).
valeur(4).
valeur(5).
valeur(6).
valeur(7).
valeur(8).
valeur(9).

%values between 1 and 9
valeur2(1).
valeur2(2).
valeur2(3).
valeur2(4).
valeur2(5).
valeur2(6).
valeur2(7).
valeur2(8).
valeur2(9).

%on définit des valeurs de 0 à 1
valeur3(0).
valeur3(1).

%definition of the sum rule and its equation
somme(RE,X,Y,Z,RS) :- C is RE+X+Y,D is Z+(10*RS),C is D.

%the predicate "solution" will be called for the execution
solution([G,E,R,A,L,D,O,N,B,T]) :- valeur2(R),
valeur2(G),
valeur(E),
valeur(A),
valeur(L),
valeur2(D),
valeur(O),
valeur(N),
valeur(B),
valeur(T),

%on ajoute la contraintes de différence 2 à 2
    G=\=E,
    R=\=E,R=\=G,
    A=\=E,A=\=G,A=\=R,
    L=\=E,L=\=G,L=\=R,L=\=A,
    D=\=E,D=\=G,D=\=R,D=\=A,D=\=L,
    O=\=E,O=\=G,O=\=R,O=\=A,O=\=L,O=\=D,
    N=\=E,N=\=G,N=\=R,N=\=A,N=\=L,N=\=D,N=\=O,
        B=\=E,B=\=G,B=\=R,B=\=A,B=\=L,B=\=D,B=\=O,B=\=N,
        T=\=E,T=\=G,T=\=R,T=\=A,T=\=L,T=\=D,T=\=O,T=\=N,T=\=B,
%-------------------------
valeur3(R5),
valeur3(R4),
valeur3(R3),
valeur3(R2),    
valeur3(R1),

somme(R1,G,D,R,0),
somme(R2,E,O,O,R1),
somme(R3,R,N,B,R2),
somme(R4,A,A,E,R3),
somme(R5,L,L,R,R4),
    somme(0,D,D,T,R5),

    gerald =:= 100000*D+10000*O+1000*N+100*A+10*L+D,
donald =:= 100000*G+10000*E+1000*R+100*A+10*L+D,
    robert =:= 100000*R+10000*O+1000*B+100*E+10*R+T,
robert =:= gerald + donald.
```

Answer (score 1):

Anniepoo suggests using CLP(FD), where you will find a range of really powerful tools for all kind of puzzles, but you have a really simple error: variables **must** be uppercase in Prolog, and your code will fail here:

```
....
gerald =:= 100000*D+10000*O+1000*N+100*A+10*L+D,
donald =:= 100000*G+10000*E+1000*R+100*A+10*L+D,
robert =:= 100000*R+10000*O+1000*B+100*E+10*R+T,
robert =:= gerald + donald.
```

try instead

```
Gerald =:= 100000*D+10000*O+1000*N+100*A+10*L+D,
Donald =:= 100000*G+10000*E+1000*R+100*A+10*L+D,
Robert =:= 100000*R+10000*O+1000*B+100*E+10*R+T,
Robert =:= Gerald + Donald.
```

beware, I didn't tested it... It's noteworthy you used variables while describing your task (`GERALD + DONALD = ROBERT`), and forgot them in actual code!

**edit**

Well, I'm sorry, I tried, but I was unable to get a solution adapting your code, I think the generate and test it's too much slow.

I arranged 'by hand' the constraints to filter early, but to no avail. Here some line from the central predicate, you can see what I mean for 'filter earlier'...

```
solution([G,E,R,A,L,D,O,N,B,T]) :-
    valeur2(G),
    valeur(E),
    G\=E,
    valeur2(R),
    R\=E,R\=G,
    valeur(A),
    A\=E,A\=G,A\=R,
    valeur(L),
    L\=E,L\=G,L\=R,L\=A,
    valeur2(D),
    D\=E,D\=G,D\=R,D\=A,D\=L,

    valeur3(R1),
    somme(R1,G,D,R,0),
    ...
```

Here a CLP(FD) solution, omitting the first digit constraint, with timing. Really easy...

```
solution([G,E,R,A,L,D], [D,O,N,A,L,D], [R,O,B,E,R,T]) :-
    Vs = [G,E,R,A,L,D,O,N,B,T],
    Vs ins 0..9,
    all_different(Vs),
    maplist(mknum,
        [ Gerald,        Donald,        Robert ],
        [[G,E,R,A,L,D], [D,O,N,A,L,D], [R,O,B,E,R,T]]),
    Gerald + Donald #= Robert,
    label(Vs).

mknum(N, [A,B,C,D,E,F]) :- N #= 100000 * A + 10000 * B + 1000 * C + 100 * D + 10 * E + F.
```

I get:

```
?- time(solution(X,Y,Z)).
% 6,138,531 inferences, 2,482 CPU in 2,484 seconds (100% CPU, 2473552 Lips)
X = [1, 9, 7, 4, 8, 5],
Y = [5, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5],
Z = [7, 2, 3, 9, 7, 0] ;
% 18,267,270 inferences, 7,311 CPU in 7,319 seconds (100% CPU, 2498725 Lips)
false.
```

Comment: @CapelliC: You can write 10^5 in place of 100000 in clpfd.

Comment: @M BenT: It will not be the very same, there will be another... I'll take a look. But note that it's worth to *simplify* the code most possible when looking for buggy details.

Comment: @false ERROR: Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found `10^4'
   Exception: (24) throw(error(domain_error(clpfd_expression, 10^4), _G3594)) ?

Comment: @MBenT: You must use an outdated version - outdated many years ago. Even SWI version 5.6.64 of 2009-10-18 has it.

Comment: @MBenT: (^)/2 is here since 2007-12-10. SWI has clpfd since 2007-08-22.

Answer (score -1):

Other than changing the letters, this puzzle's solved at

https://github.com/Anniepoo/prolog-examples/blob/master/sendmoremoney.pl

Comment: you can also search for 'puzzle([S,E,N,D] + [M,O,R,E] = [M,O,N,E,Y])' in SWI-Prolog [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.7%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpfd.html%27%29%29) documentation

Comment: -1: Citing outside sources produces linkrot with or without attribution. And this very example is, as Chac alias @CapelliC politely noted, from SWI's clpfd-manual. But it is **not** the solution, you need more to this - [see the manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html).

Comment: I have this example it works well .But in this example does not work GERALD + DONALD = ROBERT

Comment: 1 ?- solution([G,E,R,A,L,D] + [D,O,N,A,L,D] = [R,O,B,E,R,T]).

G = _G6{1..8},
E = _G9{0..9},
R = _G12{2..9},
A = _G15{0..9},
L = _G18{0..9},
D = _G21{1..8},
O = _G27{0..9},
N = _G30{0..9},
B = _G51{0..9},
T = _G60{0..9}     what is the meaning of _G6, _G9, _G12 ...

Comment: @MBenT: Your version of SWI is extremely old! [Upate now](http://www.swi-prolog.org/Download.txt)

Comment: (Version 5.6.43) what is the last version ?

Comment: @MBenT: Your version is from 2007-04-23! More than 5 years old. Current is 6.2/6.3! See [this link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/Download.txt)